# Azure CDN adds x-microsoft headers to response, What are they and how to remove?

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

Placing any content into blob storage within a container hosted on Microsoft Azure set to public blob appends various `x-ms-...` headers in the HTTP response to a standard GET request from a browser.  What are they used for, and can they be turned off?  I dislike bloated and useless HTTP headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1841396
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Sat, 05 Jan 2013 22:27:08 GMT
ETag: 0x8CFB9AAEECBA7B9
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: dca0ba01-990b-439e-b9c9-11f698222d2e
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-meta-CbModifiedTime: Thu, 27 Dec 2012 18:23:17 GMT
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2013 22:28:47 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem recently and I want to share information.

First, "x-ms-..." headers except "x-ms-meta-CbModifiedTime" is set by Azure Blob.
I think Azure Blob, Azure CDN don't support the functions remove response headers now.

However, "x-ms-meta-{name}" headers return metadata set to each blob by not Microsoft but clients.

So who does create "CbModifiedTime" metadata?

I found CloudBerry Explorer ("Cb") set this metadata automatically.
I couldn't found the way to be disable this function in Free Edition.
If you care about response headers, you should consider to use other tools

Answer (score 1):

Additional `x-microsoft` headers in the GET response can be removed using CDN endpoints **Rules engine**